# Java applet won't receive mouse focus on OSX

Tags: java, macos, applet, focus, mouse

I develop RiboVision, http://apollo.chemistry.gatech.edu/RiboVision/

Some within the last few months, my site developed a problem on macs. I use the Jmol Java applet. It is not receiving mouse focus anymore, but only on Macs, and in all browsers, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. It has to be related to some update Apple did to Java.

A really odd thing is that FirstGlance, does work on a Mac. It's basically the same Java Applet embedded in their page. http://bioinformatics.org/firstglance/fgij/fg.htm?mol=1d66&JAVA

I have no idea what I'm doing differently.

EDIT.

On a PC using Chrome, the applet works initially, but does not work after switching tabs. On a PC using firefox, it works correctly. On the mac, again, on all browsers, it doesn't work even the first time.

I don't know how to debug something so complex and elusive. No errors show in the console.

Comment: What is "mouse focus"?

Comment: I mean the ability to listen to the mouse. If you click over the applet, nothing happens. The mouse events seem to not be making it to the applet. I guess there could be another interpretation for why the applet is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Turns out, it was an issue with the z-index. I had the z-index of the Java applet set to -9000. This had no negative consequences before. I don't know when Apple changed something, but now it listens to the Z-index. I set the Z-index to something more appropriate and it's back to normal.